# Vue.js element.ui <el-upload> replace file

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to figure out how I can replace a file in `<el-upload>`

Im using [element.ui](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload) in Vue.js to make the fileupload work, however, I cant seem to find a way, to only display one file at a time.

So to be clear, I want my `file-list` to show one file at a time, and when uploading a new file, I want the old file to be replaced by the new file after the upload:

Here is what I`ve tried so far: 
This is the element.ui upload component:

```
            <el-upload v-if="row.type === 'file'"
                    class="upload-demo"
                    action="#"
                    :on-success="(file,fileList) =>{return handleUploadChange(file,fileList,attributeX,attributeY)}"
                    :file-list="logoList"
                    accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg"
                    list-type="picture"
            >
                <el-button size="small" type="primary">Click to upload</el-button>
            </el-upload>
```

the fileList stored in data:

```
data(){
logoList: [];
}
```

and the handleUploadChange function:

```
handleUploadChange(file, fileList,attrX,attrY) {
    this.logoList.shift();
}
```

However this does not seem to work at all.

So the procedure should be as follows:
1) The page is loaded - we see 1 file was already uploaded in the past.
2) The Button for the fileupload is clicked, and the file is sent to the backend etc...
3) on-success should be called after upload was sucessful, and the old file inside the file-list should be replaced by the newly uploaded file.

You can assume that there will always just be 1 file uploaded. And after the successful upload, the old file in the list should be replaced by the new file. 
Ive tried a lot of different approaches, but none seem to work.

Any help is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You should set the download limit to 2 use `ref` to intercept the downloaded data and pass it to the `filelist` and through the `:on-change` attribute, each time you call the method and delete the first element in the `fileList` if there are 2 elements in it.
Attribute `:file-list` loads data from the array (also disable automatic upload to the server `:auto-upload= "false"`)

```
<el-upload
  class="upload-demo"
  ref="upload"
  action="#"
  :limit="2"
  :file-list="fileList"
  :on-change="changeFileList"
  :auto-upload="false"
>
</el-upload>
```

Data:

```
data(){
 fileList: []
}
```

Methods:

```
changeFileList() {
  this.fileList = this.$refs.upload.uploadFiles
  if(this.fileList.length === 2) this.fileList.splice(0, 1)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<el-upload v-if="row.type === 'file'"
class="upload-demo"
action="#"
:on-change="handleUploadChange"
:file-list="logoList"
:multiple="false"
accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg"
list-type="picture"
:auto-upload="false"
>
<el-button size="small" type="primary">Click to upload</el-button>
</el-upload>
handleUploadChange(file) {
this.logoList = [file];
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to offer an explanation of what specifically you changed, and why it resolves the issue? Code is certainly welcome and useful, but it should be accompanied by an explanation, and especially when it's more than just a single expression. (This isn't that much more than a single expression, but as it's based on their original code it's hard to understand the difference at a glance.)